# How toggle elements inside this intersection observer?

Tags: javascript

I have a few elements I want to toggle wth a function, but by some reason I can't make it work. When the toggle function is executed, the console logs "cannot read the property classList of Undefined". But if I log them before the function starts I can see the elements.

Javascript

```
const toggle = element => {
    element.classList.toggle('toggle');
};

let numberOfProyects = document.getElementsByClassName('portfolio__item'),
    proyects = [],

  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfProyects.length; i++) {
    proyects[i] = document.getElementById(`proyect${i+1}`);
  
    console.log(proyects[i]);
  
    new IntersectionObserver(()=>{
      toggle(proyects[i])
    },{threshold: .6}).observe(proyects[i]);
  };
```

HTML

```
<div class="portfolio__item toggle" id="proyect1">
            <h3 class="portfolio__item-title">Podomoro Timer</h3>
            <img class="portfolio__item-img" src="assets/images/Captura de pantalla (316).png">
            <div class="portfolio__item-links">
                <div class="overlay portfolio__item-links-overlay">
                    <a target="_blank" href="https://js-codetalker.github.io/Timer/" class="portfolio__item-links-overlay-link">
                        <img src="assets/images/world.svg" class="portfolio__item-links-overlay-link-img">
                        <p class="portfolio__item-links-overlay-link-txt">Go proyect</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="overlay portfolio__item-links-overlay">
                    <a target="_blank" href="https://github.com/Js-codetalker/Timer" class="portfolio__item-links-overlay-link">
                        <img src="assets/images/github.svg" class="portfolio__item-links-overlay-link-img">
                        <p class="portfolio__item-links-overlay-link-txt">Go github</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="portfolio__item toggle" id="proyect2">
            <h3 class="portfolio__item-title">Sample Restaurant</h3>
            <img class="portfolio__item-img" src="assets/images/Captura de pantalla (317).png">
            <div class="portfolio__item-links">
                <div class="overlay portfolio__item-links-overlay">
                    <a target="_blank" href="https://js-codetalker.github.io/restaurant-example/" class="portfolio__item-links-overlay-link">
                        <img src="assets/images/world.svg" class="portfolio__item-links-overlay-link-img">
                        <p class="portfolio__item-links-overlay-link-txt">Go proyect</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="overlay portfolio__item-links-overlay">
                    <a target="_blank" href="https://github.com/Js-codetalker/restaurant-example" class="portfolio__item-links-overlay-link">
                        <img src="assets/images/github.svg" class="portfolio__item-links-overlay-link-img">
                        <p class="portfolio__item-links-overlay-link-txt">Go github</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

What I want is to create a different observer for each element in order to remove the class "toggle" when it reach the expected space in the viewport

Comment: I don't think you're using `IntersectionObserver` correctly. It's not using the intersections that are being observed.

Comment: @evolutionxbox what do you mean with that? when I scroll and reach the element the console logs an error. It isn't the intersection?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what your code does.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'm trying to execute the function "toggle" on the respective element when it reach the intersection, but its returning undefined.

Comment: What do you expect it to return? None of the functions in the example return anything? What about @vanowm's answer?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'm not expecting to return anything, just remove the class "toggle" from the selected element

Answer (score 0):

*(almost)* Always use `let` instead of `var` when defining variables inside `for` loops
Also, you don't need store your elements in second array.

```js
const toggle = element => {
    element.classList.toggle('toggle');
  console.log(element);
};

const proyects = document.getElementsByClassName('portfolio__item');

for (let i = 0; i < proyects.length; i++) {
  new IntersectionObserver(() => {
    toggle(proyects[i])
  }, {
    threshold: .6
  }).observe(proyects[i]);
};
```

```css
.container
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 20em;
  height: 10em;
}
.container > :after
{
  content: attr(id) " class is " attr(class);
}
.container > :not(.toggle) {
  background-color: pink;
}

.container >.toggle {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="portfolio__item toggle" id="proyect1">
    <h3 class="portfolio__item-title">Podomoro Timer</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio__item" id="proyect2">
    <h3 class="portfolio__item-title">Sample Restaurant (has not toggle by default)</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio__item toggle" id="proyect3">
    <h3 class="portfolio__item-title">test</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio__item toggle" id="proyect4">
    <h3 class="portfolio__item-title">test</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I already changed it, but stills returning the same error on console

Comment: Works fine in my tests (added snippet), perhaps your html is not what javascript is expecting.
However your example produces a different error, caused by a comma in `proyects = [],`

Comment: I already added the HTML code. Can you check it out? I did by myself, but found nothing.

Comment: Your code works fine with changing to `let` and removing the comma. I've updated the answer with a better demo and reduced code